# PowerShell Out-File is not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

The following line of my code simply does not write to file the `Out-File` command:

```bsh
Move-Item $item.Path $CaminhoCompleto -Force -WhatIf -Verbose |
    Out-File -Filepath $SaidaTXT -Append -NoClobber
```

On the screen it shows correctly, but the file is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-WhatIf` messages are written directly to the console and can't be [piped or redirected](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) without running the statement in a different PowerShell process. You  can capture the output with [`Start-Transcript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript), though.

```
Start-Transcript -Path $SaidaTXT -Append
Move-Item ...
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed, then I used Start-Transcript.


Thanks.